QGIS : "Labels settings" vs "text font" symbol libraries : how to use them distinctively?
Using the QGIS symbol manager, I defined a green text font :

I defined as well a red buffer label settings :

And now, i want to use them in my project :

I used the red buffer label settings. All is OK. All the parameters are updated.
Then, I used the green font. I imagine that only the font parameters will be updated.
But, all the labels paramaters seems to be updated : font, buffer, mask, shadow ….  (i.e : I lost my red buffer)
It seems that, whatever the type of label settings extent chosen,"label full settings" or "font settings only", all the parameters are always updated when I use my predefinited sets.
Is there something wrong in the way I use QGIS?
